# iOS Swift SpriteKit Achieving a sprite "explosion" effect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite

In my game I would like that when a collision occurs, the designated sprite would undergo an "explosion" or "glass break" effect, in which the sprite is split up into random pieces which are then moved at a random rate, speed, and angle. I would imagine that something like this may require using particles or at the very a least texture atlas.

I found a little bit on this, but the questions/explantations were catered for Objective-C. I am fairly new to iOS development and have solely used swift, so I can't really translate from one language to another. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to try using the SpriteKit Emitter class for this. Add a new SpriteKit Particle Effect file to the project and configure the type of explosion there. You do not need any code, to configure it as Apple has very conveniently provided an editor window for us to easily change the values.

Once you are satisfied with the way the emitter looks, you can then open the Game Scene (assuming that is where this collision would be detected) and type:

```
let explosionEmitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:"the file name")
sprite.addChild(explosionEmitterNode)
```

Here sprite is the actual node to which you would like to add the emitter effect to. Or you could add it to the scene directly and set its position as:

```
let explosionEmitterNode = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed:"the file name")
explosionEmitterNode.position = CGPointMake(200,300)
addChild(explosionEmitterNode)
```